# jQuery - .append() with .fadeIn() not working

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-events, dom-manipulation

I am having some trouble getting this working:

```
$("#cloud1").live("mouseenter", function() {
$(this).append('<div class="cloud1"><img src="http://mercury-consulting.theportlandco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/1.png" width="470" height="400"/></div>');
$(this).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Its not fading in when I hover over the div, it just appears.  Not sure what the issue it - please let me know!

Comment: try `$('.cloud1', this).fadeIn('slow');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your element is already visible. Try this example

```
$("#cloud1").live("mouseenter", function() {
   $(this).append('<div class="cloud1" style="display:none"><img src="http://mercury-consulting.theportlandco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/1.png" width="470" height="400"/></div>')
    .find('div.cloud1').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, that when you append a div, it will already become visible. So you have to hide it beforehand. Check out my [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/HFvSx/).

```
$("#cloud1").live("mouseenter", function() {
  $('<div class="cloud1"><img src="http://mercury-consulting.theportlandco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/1.png" width="470" height="400"/></div>')
    .hide()
    .appendTo(this)
    .fadeIn('slow');
});
```

An alternative solution might be to add this to your stylesheet:

```
.cloud1 { display: none; }
```

So whenever something with the class of `cloud1` is appended, it will be hidden by default, so `fadeIn()` will work as expected.

**Appendix:** you also might want to check if the div is already added, because otherwise whenever the mouseenter event happens, a new div will be appended.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#cloud1").live("mouseenter", function() {
    var div = $('<div class="cloud1"><img src="http://mercury-consulting.theportlandco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/1.png" width="470" height="400"/></div>').hide(); 
    $(this).append(div);
    div.fadeIn('slow');
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/z5j2Q/1/)

Comment: I'm using `slideDown()` instead of `fadeIn()`, same time I want to scroll to the bottom of page how do I do ?